# How to use Natural Language Processing (AI) in app lab?

Tags: code.org, app-lab

I know about NLP being used in js but now , I am asked to do it in app lab.

I tried a lot of research but found no way to do it in blocks, app lab in code.org.

It should understand various diseases.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While NLP isn't entirely supported natively in App Lab, you can try using the `getPrediction()` block. Its documentation is listed [here](https://studio.code.org/docs/applab/getPrediction/).